# How can i call my API in EC2 instance(ubuntu 16.04) using docker container

Tags: php, docker, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

i call my api with following port:

> http://IPv4 Public IP:8000/login

and i pull code through docker compose up. this will will give me all project configuration with php 7.1.8

```
php artisan serve
```

command will start successfully on 127.0.0.1:8000 this port.

but i use AWS EC2(ubuntu 16.04) instance. so, i call API "IPv4 Public IP:8000/login" in postman.

but it's give me an error:

**could not get any response**

there was an error connecting to IPv4 Public IP:8000/login

Comment: Maulik kanani is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using docker container it will allocate a port in your runing image

```
eg: your image is runing on 0.0.0.81
```

so you can set security group as "custom TCP rule" in 81 port
and it's runing

and your API call are runing like

```
http://youIp:81/api
```